# Best gutter option

Tags: gutters

[image]
[image]

Need to add a section of gutter in front of my house. Would like to not have another downspout. Would it better to move the existing one over(which would block the plumbing vent)(pic 2)? Or put the downspout on the left side having corner pieces on both sides(pic 1)?

Comment: You didn't add any pics ... [Edit] your question and use the "sun & mountains" button to add them.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to move the downspout to left, the added gutter would need to be lower than the existing gutter to get water flowing to the left. Is that practical? The far-right end of the gutter might have to be raised to get flow.

There are Y-downspout funnels, such as this [from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D5CI1ZG) or this [from Aquabarrel](https://www.aquabarrel.com/y-funnels-tie-in-c-33_344y-downspout-funnel-rectangular-p-1000689.html). Whether it would be appropriate to join the two gutters, and whether the downspout could handle the combined flow is another question.

On the other hand, there appears to be no gutter to the *left* of the bay window. If you're thinking of adding one, then you might as well plan the slope accordingly and put that downspout at the far left of the house.

Comment: I see gutter on the left, just like the one on the right.  I do agree that the best course of action here would be to have a second downspout  from the new gutter to the wall, and combine them on the wall with a wye.